# How to talk to best friend about broken trust?

Tags: friends

I have a crush on a guy in my school, and I told my best friend about it.

I recently found out that he started dating a girl who happens to be friends with my best friend. A couple days after that my crush's girlfriend (we're not friends, but she's one of the nicest girls in school) came to me at lunch, and told me that she knew that I had a crush on her boyfriend, and that my best friend had told her.

I denied it, but now I don't know what to say to my friend. I told her about my crush in confidence, and she not only told her friend, but his girlfriend of all people!

How should I approach her about the fact that she betrayed my trust?

Comment: I'm sorry, Emily, but we're not here to tell you what to do. We need you to tell us what you want to do or what you want to happen and we can explain how you might achieve it. We also need more information from you if we're going to help... for example, your age, where in the world you are... I'm putting this on hold until you [edit] it to do these things.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is asking us to tell them what choice to make, rather than asking how to achieve a specific goal.

Comment: Hello Emily, I've edited your post to be in line with the site guidelines, and also to ask the question that I _think_ you were trying to get an answer to. Please edit it further, if you feel I missed the mark. Best of luck!

Comment: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/448/confronting-a-friend-about-a-betrayal-of-a-confidence?rq=1

Comment: I voted to reopen but then saw the question I linked above. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

Have a talk with her about it, if this is the first time your trust has been broken by said person, then an open talk about how you feel about her actions will help get both of you on the same page. Share your honest feelings about what transpired and see how she takes it.

If she agrees not to do it again, then let it go and hope for the best.

if she fights and insists that she is correct, then i think i can safely say that you should not confide in this friend again.

As for the damage done to the exposing of your secret, there is no way for words to be taken back.